# How to get the result set even if the foreign key is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, key

I'm using the following query to get the invoice details.So, i need to get the invoice details even if there is no customer registered for the invoice. So in that case, the foreign key `cusidfk` in invoice table is null. So how can I get the result set? how can I show null for the customer in the same result set?

```
SELECT invoice.invno,invoice.invdate,invoice.invtime,customer.bizname,invoice.addedby,item.nameinsin,invoicedetails.price,invoicedetails.soldprice,invoicedetails.qty,invoicedetails.subtotal,invoicedetails.total,payment.pamt,invoice.tot
FROM invoice, invoicedetails, item, customer, payment
WHERE invoice.invno=invoicedetails.invnofk
  AND invoicedetails.itemfkcode=item.itemcode
  AND customer.cusid=invoice.cusidfk
  AND invoicedetails.invnofk='0000000000005'
  AND invoice.invno=payment.invfkno
```

Comment: `… AND (customer.cusid=invoice.cusidfk OR invoice.cusidfk IS NULL) AND …`? Btw., you should have said/tagged with DBMS you are using …

Comment: CBroe : I'm using MySQL server.... could you please explain more about how can I make this query work even the foreign key is null?

Comment: Didn’t I just try that …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` rather than implicit joining.

```
SELECT ...
FROM invoice
JOIN invoicedetails ON invoice.invno = invoicedetails.invnofk
JOIN item ON invoicedetails.itemfkcode = item.itemcode
JOIN payment ON invoice.invno = payment.invfkno
LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.cusid = invoice.cusidfk
WHERE invoicedetails.invnofk = '0000000000005'
```

With `LEFT JOIN` all `customer` fields will be `NULL` if no entry exists.

Comment: @user2765079 you can appreciate the answer and express your thankfulness by accepting the answer of Dukeling.